# Problemas com UTF-8 ISO-8859-1 mysql php acentuação �

Tags: php, acentuação

Pessoal estou com problema de acentuação usando PHP/Mysql

Quando uso:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",true);
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

o código HTML fica ok, porem resultados do MySQL com acentuação fica com �.

Se altero pra:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true);
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

o problema inverte, os resultados do banco ficam ok e html fica:

PrÃ³ximo (ex: Próximo)

Ja mudei base de dados pra Latin1 e voltei pra UTF-8 e nada. 
Tentei utf8_encode(), htmlentities() e continua na mesma.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Tenta user isso `CREATE DATABASE mydb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss as informações lá não resolveram

Comment: @LucasCarezia já tentei com utf8 e latin1 .. mesmo resultado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se caso seu banco de dados esteja com uma codificação diferente do seu código você pode utilizar pode exemplo no PHP:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8'");
```

Substitua o **'utf8'** para sua codificação preferencial. Mas o ideal é analisar se seus arquivos de código e o banco de dados estão com a codificação padrão assim não terá estes problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Em sua conexão, utilize o set_charset:

```
$connMysql = mysql_connect('localhost', $myUser, $myPass);
mysql_select_db($database, $connMysql);
mysql_set_charset('UTF8');
```